# Unable to get Shiny Output for Prediction Model

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am new to Shiny App and seek some help from experienced users.
Problem:
I want to create a user input shiny app in which the user will enter the values and he/she will get the desired output in the app. e.g. put all 13 variables and get the median value of the house corresponding to that. I tried with the below code but it doesn't generate output.

For better reproduceability I have used the Boston Housing data.

```
library(rpart)

set.seed(1234)
train_index <- sample(nrow(Boston),0.75*nrow(Boston))
boston_train <- Boston[train_index,]   
boston_test <- Boston[-train_index,]

boston.rpart <- rpart(formula = medv ~ ., data = boston_train)

train_pred <- predict(object = boston.rpart)
test_pred <- predict(boston.rpart, boston_test)

library(shiny)
ui = fluidPage(

  titlePanel(" Boston Housing Model"),
  sidebarLayout(position = "left",
                sidebarPanel(

                  sliderInput("selectCrim", "crim:",min = 0., max = 100,value =10 , step = 1),
                  sliderInput("selectZn", "zn:",min = 0., max = 100,value = 10, step = 1),
                  sliderInput("selectIndus", "indus:",min = 0., max = 100,value = 11, step = 1),
                  sliderInput("selectChas", "chas:",min = 0., max = 1,value = 0, step = 1),
                  sliderInput("selectNox", "nox:",min = 0., max = 1,value = 0.5, step = 0.1),
                  sliderInput("selectRm", "rm:",min = 0, max = 10,value = 5, step = 1),
                  sliderInput("selectAge", "age:",min = 0, max = 100,value = 50, step = 1),
                  sliderInput("selectDis", "dis:",min = 0, max = 20,value = 5, step = 1),
                  sliderInput("selectRad", "rad:",min = 1, max = 24,value = 12, step = 1),
                  sliderInput("selectTax", "tax:",min = 100, max = 1000, value = 500, step = 100),
                  sliderInput("selectPtratio", "ptratio:",min = 10, max = 30,value = 20, step = 1),
                  sliderInput("selectBlack", "black:",min = 0., max = 400,value = 250, step = 50),
                  sliderInput("selectLstat", "lstat:",min = 0, max = 100,value = 40, step = 1),
                  submitButton('Submit')

                ),
                mainPanel("Pred")
  )
)

server = function (input,output) {
  data <- reactive({
        data.frame(crim=input$selectCrim,
           zn=input$selectZn,
           indus=input$selectIndus,
           chas=input$selectChas,
           nox=input$selectNox,
           rm=input$selectRm,
           age=input$selectAge,
           dis=input$selectDis,
           rad=input$selectRad,
           tax=input$selectTax,
           ptratio=input$selectPtratio,
           black=input$selectBlack,
           lstat=input$selectLstat
               )
  })

  pred <- reactive({
    predict(boston.rpart,data())
  })

  output$Pred <- renderText(pred())
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Please check the input ids and change the objects in dataframe to match them to that id of `sliderInput`'s. For example, `input$crim` should be `input$selectCrim` etc.

Comment: And if the submit button should do something, you have to add an `observeEvent`

Comment: I made both changes but it seems the problem is in the final lines of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working version of your code.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(" Boston Housing Model"),
  sidebarLayout(
    position = "left",
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("selectCrim", "crim:",min = 0., max = 100,value =10 , step = 1),
      sliderInput("selectZn", "zn:",min = 0., max = 100,value = 10, step = 1),
      sliderInput("selectIndus", "indus:",min = 0., max = 100,value = 11, step = 1),
      sliderInput("selectChas", "chas:",min = 0., max = 1,value = 0, step = 1),
      sliderInput("selectNox", "nox:",min = 0., max = 1,value = 0.5, step = 0.1),
      sliderInput("selectRm", "rm:",min = 0, max = 10,value = 5, step = 1),
      sliderInput("selectAge", "age:",min = 0, max = 100,value = 50, step = 1),
      sliderInput("selectDis", "dis:",min = 0, max = 20,value = 5, step = 1),
      sliderInput("selectRad", "rad:",min = 1, max = 24,value = 12, step = 1),
      sliderInput("selectTax", "tax:",min = 100, max = 1000, value = 500, step = 100),
      sliderInput("selectPtratio", "ptratio:",min = 10, max = 30,value = 20, step = 1),
      sliderInput("selectBlack", "black:",min = 0., max = 400,value = 250, step = 50),
      sliderInput("selectLstat", "lstat:",min = 0, max = 100,value = 40, step = 1)
    ),
    mainPanel(textOutput("Pred"))
  )
)    
server <- function(input,output) {
  output$Pred <- renderText({
    data <- data.frame(crim=input$selectCrim,
      zn=input$selectZn, indus=input$selectIndus,
      chas=input$selectChas, nox=input$selectNox,
      rm=input$selectRm, age=input$selectAge,
      dis=input$selectDis, rad=input$selectRad,
      tax=input$selectTax, ptratio=input$selectPtratio,
      black=input$selectBlack, lstat=input$selectLstat)
    predict(boston.rpart, data)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the `submitButton` behaved weird in combination with storing the inputs in a data.frame. I'm not really sure what is going on here, but a solution is to use an `actionButton` with `observeEvent` instead.

Another problem in your code is that you didn't specify the `textOutput` correctly. Also, I would additionally use these brackets `{}` for a render function, because apparently if you don't sometimes `R` behaves weirdly.

```
library(rpart)

set.seed(1234)
library(mlbench)
data(BostonHousing)
Boston <- BostonHousing
train_index <- sample(nrow(Boston),0.75*nrow(Boston))
boston_train <- Boston[train_index,]   
boston_test <- Boston[-train_index,]

boston.rpart <- rpart(formula = medv ~ ., data = boston_train)

train_pred <- predict(object = boston.rpart)
test_pred <- predict(boston.rpart, boston_test)

library(shiny)
ui = fluidPage(

  titlePanel(" Boston Housing Model"),
  sidebarLayout(position = "left",
                sidebarPanel(

                  sliderInput("selectCrim", "crim:",min = 0., max = 100,value =10 , step = 1),
                  sliderInput("selectZn", "zn:",min = 0., max = 100,value = 10, step = 1),
                  sliderInput("selectIndus", "indus:",min = 0., max = 100,value = 11, step = 1),
                  sliderInput("selectChas", "chas:",min = 0., max = 1,value = 0, step = 1),
                  sliderInput("selectNox", "nox:",min = 0., max = 1,value = 0.5, step = 0.1),
                  sliderInput("selectRm", "rm:",min = 0, max = 10,value = 5, step = 1),
                  sliderInput("selectAge", "age:",min = 0, max = 100,value = 50, step = 1),
                  sliderInput("selectDis", "dis:",min = 0, max = 20,value = 5, step = 1),
                  sliderInput("selectRad", "rad:",min = 1, max = 24,value = 12, step = 1),
                  sliderInput("selectTax", "tax:",min = 100, max = 1000, value = 500, step = 100),
                  sliderInput("selectPtratio", "ptratio:",min = 10, max = 30,value = 20, step = 1),
                  sliderInput("selectBlack", "black:",min = 0., max = 400,value = 250, step = 50),
                  sliderInput("selectLstat", "lstat:",min = 0, max = 100,value = 40, step = 1),
                  actionButton('submitButton', "Submit")

                ),
                mainPanel(textOutput("Pred"))
  )
)

server = function (input,output) {
  data <- reactive({
    data.frame(crim=input$selectCrim,
               zn=input$selectZn,
               indus=input$selectIndus,
               chas=as.factor(input$selectChas),
               nox=input$selectNox,
               rm=input$selectRm,
               age=input$selectAge,
               dis=input$selectDis,
               rad=input$selectRad,
               tax=input$selectTax,
               ptratio=input$selectPtratio,
               black=input$selectBlack,
               lstat=input$selectLstat
    )
  })

  pred <- reactive({
    predict(boston.rpart,data())
  })

  observeEvent(input$submitButton, {
    output$Pred <- renderText({pred()})

  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Note: As I used the data from the `mlbench` package, `chas` has to be a factor.